# Cascading vpn routing (openvpn + shrewsoft)

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking

I have a personal VPN between my mobile devices and my LAN created via openVPN server on my debian server.

Assume that my LAN class *192.168.1.0/24* on interface *eth0*, my VPN is a standard *10.0.8.0/24* on *tun0* interface.

Then on my server I have another VPN, with my server being a client, built on Shrewsoft VPN.

Let’s say that this VPN grants me access to the *10.50.0.0/24* subnet via *tap0* interface

All I want to do is to reach the host *10.50.0.15* from my openvpn clients.

I only have access to the server+openVPN server configuration and I’m a bit confused at the moment.

The ways i tried to achieve the result are:

1. 1:1 NAT the host *10.50.0.15* on *192.168.1.15*
2. Try to route the traffic on my server towards *10.50.0.0/24* and coming from *10.0.8.0/24* through the shrewsoft gw.

I am short in ideas, I would appreciate any suggestions!

Thank you. A

**********************EDIT**************************

No good news after trying everything that was suggested, even with a clean iptables configuration I am not able to route correctly the traffic.

What i see with tshark is that the packet is correctly routed to 10.50.0.15, but the response comes on the TAP0 IP (192.168.11.150), and is not correctly forwarded to openvpn LAN.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have IP forwarding enabled in your `iptables` (table `filter`, chain `FORWARD`) for your `tun0` interface.
- Make sure tou have IP forwarding enabled in the kernel (`/sbin/sysctl -a | grep forward` — please work from there).
- Make sure you have `push` directive in your OpenVPN server configuration which tell its clients that the `10.50.0.0/24` network is reachable via `10.0.8.1` — that is, the OpenVPN server's IP; see ["routed LANs"](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans).
- You might also need an appropriate `iroute` directive in the OpenVPN's config; see the guide above.

The reasoning:

- An IP client — let's consider your mobile clients — uses its local routing table to decide where to send a packet with a particular destination IP address.  Any client has one or more directly connected networks and zero or more indirectly connected networks.

  The indirectly connected networks are reachable via the so-called "gateways" whose task is to forward the packets.
  Obviously, all the gateways must be reachable via directly or indirectly connected networks.

  To consider the simplest case, a client on a LAN with a single server providing a connection to the Internet for that LAN, typically has two entries in its routing table:

  - The address of its LAN — with the specification it's directly corrected.
  - The IP address of the gateway server on that LAN, marked as the so-called "default" routing entry.

  This setup makes the client sent all the packets destined to the hosts on that LAN directly via its network interface connected to the LAN, and send all other traffic to that gateway server.
- For your clients, `10.0.8/24` is a directly connected network —
  once the OpenVPN client successfully connects to the server.
  Now, to reach `10.50.0.0/24` via the OpenVPN's tunnel, the clients
  must have a new rule into their route table to know that that network
  is available via a certain gateway—which is your OpenVPN server.
- So you set up proper routing and IP forwarding on your server first
  and then make sure the clients know where to send packets destined to hosts on `10.50.0.0/24`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete reply, the point is that I managed to correctly route the traffic towards the host, but the return packet isn't correctly forwarded back to the VPN subnet.
In detail, using tcpdump for the host 10.50.0.15 both on tun0 and eth0 i see the request going correctly from tun0 to the 10.50.0.0/24 gateway, and the response has source 10.50.0.15 and destination my server IP 192.168.1.65. 
The rules i have are:

POSTROUTING with -o eth0 MASQUERADE for openvpn
FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT 

Am I missing something?
Thank you

Comment: From this scarce info, I'd say you're missing `FORWARD -d 10.8.0.0/24` as well—that is, you allow forwarding packets from (`-s` == source) that network but not *to* it (`-d` == destination).

Comment: As a general rule, it's sometimes advisable to temporarily set everything to "all permitted" (such as `iptables -P FORWARD allow`) make sure it all works and then tighten by *disabling* everything and then punching the necessary holes" ;-)

Comment: Oh, and I'm not sure you need masquerading/NAT for OpenVPN—quite contrary, the clients and the server talk via the server's public IP, and all the traffic carried by the VPN is on the VPN's private network, so no NAT is needed.

Comment: Even commenting all the lines and leaving an "ALL ACCEPT" configuration i get the same result, I'm really having a bad time with this tricky configuration!

Comment: I figured out what is happening, the packets from tun0 to 10.50.0.0/24 are correctly routed, the answer coming from 10.50.0.15 is correctly routed to the tap0 bridge, but then the packet is lost, and doesn't get back to the VPN, how can i do?